# Linux network driver question

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers

I am trying to understand more on the linux network drivers and user mode drivers. Have few questions. I searched online and have found few resources but are not clear enough

Linux kernel driver

Does linux nw driver handle multiple same devices for pkt rx and tx? How does linux nw driver figure out multiple devices?

Comment: So, thanks for restricting yourself to one question. This is still incredibly broad. So your first question can be answered with a clear "yes, why should Linux handle multiple cards of the same type differently than multiple cards of different types?"

Answer (score 1):

> Does linux nw driver handle multiple same devices for pkt rx and tx?

Yes.

> How does linux nw driver figure out multiple devices?

Same as every other operating system handles all types of devices: You hold one data structure that contains references to card registers, state, buffers etc. **per device**. Doing it any other way would be complicated. You need to store all these things anyways, whether you have one network interface card, or a hundred.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Does it mean it has to keep metadata for each device ie lets say DMA addresses? Does it store this info keyed on mac address to ensure proper data tx and rx?

Comment: again, this is nothing special about linux. On every microcontroller you need to know at which address your individual peripheral lives.

Comment: Keyed in MAC address: no, not really. That's not a concept that's necessary at the driver level, it becomes relevant in the network stack that *uses* these drivers.

Comment: then how does it move the data to the appropriate device. Say app does a send and the stack now has to send it on the wire through one of the devices. Since only 1 driver is loaded how does the driver pick the appropriate device to send out?

Comment: that's not the driver's job, that's the routing table in the network stack.

Comment: Thanks Marcus for patiently answering. I am still confused. Say I have two of the same cards. Now when data comes to the card, assume mmap is done for these pkts. we use either interrupt or poll mode. Now these pkts need to be pulled. How does the driver distinguish which card it has to send the data to or revcieve from?

Comment: again, nothing to do with Linux: a PCIe card raises a *specific* interrupt. If you're on a system where that's not the case, your operating system must check all the devices that could have caused a specific interrupt whether it was them. For network cards, that's very easy: the card will have received a packet, put it into memory, and inserted an RX buffer descriptor in its RX buffer descriptor ringbuffer; the operating system would just have to check the current read pointer position in that interface-specific ringbuffer.

Comment: I don't really know why you think anything would be special if two cards were of the same type. That's simply not the case – no sensible person would write a driver so that it assumes only one instance of a card, because it's actively hard and bad to do. If you're a driver, you get told where your card sits, which memory regions it has. A driver is in the end, just a library of functions to be called on data structures; and if there's two cards, with one isolated data structure each.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150375/discussion-between-ram-and-marcus-muller).